# MySQL o PHP Sumar y obtener rangos de fechas

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una base de datos en MySQL, y trabajo en un proyecto de PHP la cual tiene entre otros los siguientes datos y campos:

| id | Valor | Inicio | Fin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 | 30/01/2022 | 30/10/2022 |
| 2 | 100 | 25/02/2022 | 20/06/2022 |

Con los datos anteriores quiero obtener sea una vista en MySQL o una consulta desde PHP para crear una nueva tabla MySQL que me muestre lo siguiente:

| Valor | Inicio | Fin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | 30/01/2022 | 25/02/2022 |
| 220 | 25/02/2022 | 20/06/2022 |
| 120 | 20/06/2022 | 30/10/2022 |

Los datos de valores, fechas y rangos varían bastante, en la base de datos tengo hasta 6 items

He intentado el siguiente código en PHP, Laravel:

```
$data = DB::table('invests')
                  ->select('date_start', 'date_end', 'user_id', 'amount')
                  ->orderBy('user_id','ASC')
                  ->groupBy('id', 'user_id')
                  ->get(); 
          $user_ant=null; 
          $datos=collect();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $cambio=false;
        if (!isset($inicio_a)){
            $inicio_a = $value->date_start;
            $max = $fin_a = $value->date_end;
            $desde = $value->date_start;
            $hasta = $hasta_final = $value->date_end;
            $valor  = $value->amount;
            dump('si entra 1');
        }
        else{
            
            $inicio_b = $value->date_start;
            $fin_b = $value->date_end;
            if ($fin_a > $inicio_b){
               $valor2 = $value->amount;
               $cambio=true;
               $hasta = min($fin_a, $inicio_b);

            }
            else{
                $valor2 = -$value->amount;
                $cambio=true;

            } 
            $hasta2 = min($fin_a, $inicio_b);
            $desde2 = min($fin_a, $inicio_b);
            $hasta_final= $fin_b;
        }

        
        if ($cambio==true){
            $datos->push('desde: '.$desde);
            $datos->push('hasta: '.$hasta);
            $datos->push('valor: '.$valor);
            $desde = $desde2;
            $hasta = $hasta2;
            $valor+=$valor2;
        }

      }
            $datos->push('desde: '.$desde);
            $datos->push('hasta: '.$hasta);
            $datos->push('valor: '.$hasta_final);
```

Pero no me funciona como espero.

Comment: ¿Cuál versión de MySQL?

Comment: es la version 5.6

Comment: @Ruben una pregunta cuando se sumen las dos fechas en que tipo lo quieres, en días, horas, mes, semana, etc

Comment: Saludos @JavierG.Raya, lo que quiero es ubicar los datos, de tal manera que el valor se acumule, pero tambien se decremente cuando un periodo termine. gracias por responder

Comment: Entonces ya no se amigo @Ruben

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres ***sumar dos fechas en MySQL*** puedes usar la función `DATE_ADD`, Esta tiene Intervalos de días, horas, minutos, etc. la cual se puede sumar.

```
select DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 DAY); # Agrega 10 días a la fecha actual
select DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE); # Agrega 15minutos a la fecha actual
select DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR); # Agrega 2 años a la fecha actual
select DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL '1-11' YEAR_MONTH); # Agrega 1 años 11 meses a la fecha actual
```

***Tipo de valores Disponibles :***

- **Microsegundos :** `MICROSECOND`
- **Segundos :** `SECOND`
- **Minutos :** `MINUTE`
- **Horas :** `HOUR`
- **Días :** `DAY`
- **Semana :** `WEEK`
- **Meses :** `MONTH`
- **Años :** `YEAR`
- **Segundo Microsegundo :** `SECOND_MICROSECOND`
- **Minuto Microsegundo :** `MINUTE_MICROSECOND`
- **Minuto Segundo :** `MINUTE_SECOND`
- **Hora Microsegundo :** `HOUR_MICROSECOND`
- **Hora Segundo :** `HOUR_SECOND`
- **Hora Minuto :** `HOUR_MINUTE`
- **Día Microsegundo :** `DAY_MICROSECOND`
- **Día Segundo :** `DAY_SECOND`
- **Día Minuto :** `DAY_MINUTE`
- **Días Horas :** `DAY_HOUR`
- **Años meses :** `YEAR_MONTH`

[<kbd>Ejecutar Ejemplo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/237)